# inconsistent diagnostics across compilers for narrowing conversions in non-type template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, non-type

```
template <bool>
void f() { }

int main ()
{
    constexpr long long int num = 5;
    f<num & 4>(); // bitwise & is intended
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 9 has a problem:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f<(5 & 4)>()'
error: narrowing conversion of '4' from 'long long int' to 'bool' [-Wnarrowing]
```

clang has a problem:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f'
```

gcc 8 and msvc compile without errors.

Who is correct? I think the error is correct but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ill-formed because for [template non-type argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments),

> The template argument that can be used with a non-type template parameter can be any [converted constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) of the type of the template parameter.

And the narrow conversion is not considered as [converted constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression).

> A *converted constant expression* of type T is an expression [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression, and the implicit conversion sequence contains only:
>
> - ...
> - non-narrowing integral conversions
> - ...

Comment: Should a conforming compiler diagnose it?

Comment: @Yashas I'm not sure about MSVC, gcc seems having fixed from [gcc 9.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eljblUae6HLelai1).

Comment: @Yashas Yes, a conforming compiler should diagnose.

Comment: Is this answer applicable to c++11?

Comment: @Yashas Yes, I checked the C++11 standard, [temp.arg.nontype#1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.arg.nontype#1.1), *for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the template-parameter;* And [expr.const#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#3), *and integral conversions ([conv.integral]) other than narrowing conversions*